# ExpandableListView- Update or Remove a particular Row without calling the adapter in Activity

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have implemented an expandableListview after fetching data from database.
The data is coming properly in the list, onClicking() on the child item details page is opening where user can delete the data and also edit the data. But again after returning to the MainActivity I have to call the Adpater class inside **OnResume** to reload the data which I don't want. I just want to **remove** or show the **updated** data.
I have tried with **notifyDataSetChanged()** but it didn't work, may be I have used it in the wrong place.Please guide me a little...

Adapter Class..

```
public class TransExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<ExcelDataModel> list_shareofshelf;

    public TransExpAdapter(Context context, List<ExcelDataModel> list_shareofshelf) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list_shareofshelf = list_shareofshelf;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View cview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_sos, null);

        RelativeLayout child_container = cview.findViewById(R.id.child_container);
        TextView tv_category = cview.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
        TextView tv_expense = cview.findViewById(R.id.tv_expense);
        ImageView iv_icon = cview.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);

        try {
            if (list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getIcon_name() != null &&
                    !list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getIcon_name().isEmpty()) {
                int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getIcon_name(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                iv_icon.setImageResource(imageid);
            } else {
                iv_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gray_no_img);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            iv_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gray_no_img);
        }

        if (list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getIncome_Expenses().equalsIgnoreCase("Expenses")) {
            tv_expense.setText("-" + list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getAmount());
        } else {
            tv_expense.setText(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getAmount());

        }


        child_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getId().isEmpty()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, ExpenseDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra("trans_id", list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getId());
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });

        if (!list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getMemo().isEmpty()) {
            tv_category.setText(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getMemo());
        } else {
            tv_category.setText(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getCategory());
        }

        if (expandedListPosition == list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().size() - 1) {
            child_container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_bottom_round);
        }

        return cview;
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return list_shareofshelf.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent_sos, null);
        ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        eLV.expandGroup(listPosition);
        TextView listTitleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

        TextView tv_expenditures = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_expenditures);
        listTitleTextView.setText(Utils.getFormattedDate(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getDate()));

        tv_expenditures.setText("Expenses: " + list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getExp_amt_() + " Income: " + list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getInc_amt_());


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }
}
```

MainActivity Call...

```
private class AsyncTaskGetTransactionData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            list_final_transaction_data = db.getTransactionDetails(current_month);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (list_final_transaction_data.size() > 0) {
                expandableListAdapter = new TransExpAdapter(context, list_final_transaction_data);
                expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
                expandableListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new AsyncTaskSummationExpenses().execute();
            } else {
                tv_income.setText("0");
                tv_expenses.setText("0");
                tv_balance.setText("0");
                p.dismiss();
                expandableListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

////Database Method

```
 public List<ExcelDataModel> getTransactionDetails(String current_month) {
        List<ExcelDataModel> listProd = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("CurrentMonthDB", current_month);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            String selectQuery = "select f.date,(select sum(amount) from tbl_transactions WHERE trans_type='Expenses' and date=f.date)exp, " +
                    "(select sum(amount) from tbl_transactions where trans_type='Income' and date=f.date)inc from tbl_transactions f where f.date like '%" + current_month + "%' GROUP by f.date ORDER BY strftime('%s', f.date) desc";

            Log.d("FirstQuery", selectQuery);
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ExcelDataModel foc_cat = new ExcelDataModel();
                    String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    String income = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("inc"));
                    String expense = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("exp"));
                    String selectQuery1 = "select * from tbl_transactions a LEFT join tbl_category b where a.cat_id=b.cat_id and date='" + date + "' order by memo asc";
                    Log.d("SecondQuery", selectQuery1);
                    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
                    if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
                        List<ExcelDataModel> subCat_list = new ArrayList<>();
                        // ExcelDataModel pp_dummy = new ExcelDataModel();
                        //pp_dummy.setId("");
                        // subCat_list.add(pp_dummy);
                        do {
                            ExcelDataModel prod_subcat = new ExcelDataModel();
                            prod_subcat.setDate(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("date")));
                            prod_subcat.setIncome_Expenses(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("trans_type")));
                            prod_subcat.setCategory(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("cat_name")));
                            prod_subcat.setMemo(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("memo")));
                            prod_subcat.setAmount(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("amount")));
                            prod_subcat.setId(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("trans_id")));
                            prod_subcat.setIcon_name(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("cat_iconname")));
                            subCat_list.add(prod_subcat);
                        } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
                        foc_cat.setDate(date);

                        if (expense != null) {
                            foc_cat.setExp_amt_(Double.parseDouble(expense));
                        } else {
                            foc_cat.setExp_amt_(0);
                        }

                        if (income != null) {
                            foc_cat.setInc_amt_(Double.parseDouble(income));
                        } else {
                            foc_cat.setInc_amt_(0);
                        }

                        foc_cat.setDate(date);
                        foc_cat.setGroupFocAll(subCat_list);
                        listProd.add(foc_cat);
                        cursor2.close();
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (db != null)
                db.close();
        }
        return listProd;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a callBack on the `OnClick()` of the child and catch that callback in the activity, so you can do `startActivityForResult()` instead of just `startActivity()`.

That way you can know when the user deletes something in the details activity, right after that activity is destroyed. Then, in the `onActivityResult` you do `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Like so, in the adapter:

```
child_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         if (!list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getId().isEmpty()) {
              callback.childClicked(list_shareofshelf.get(listPosition).getGroupFocAll().get(expandedListPosition).getId());
         }
     }
});
```

Then, in your activity, you implement the callBack

```
@Override
public void childClicked(int id){
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ExpenseDetails.class);
    i.putExtra("trans_id", id);
    startActivityForResult(i, yourRequestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
    Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == yourRequestCode) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_DELETED) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok @Rodrigo Serra let me try